# Delete a particular row from a table in SQLite which has a composite primary key

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have written this code to delete a row from one of the tables in my SQLite Database which has a composite primary key. I have an image button in the RecyclerView after clicking on which this action should take place. But this code is not working for me.

This is my adapter class:

```
public class adapter_cgpa extends RecyclerView.Adapter<adapter_cgpa.Viewholder> {

    ArrayList<POJO> cgpaArrayList;


    public adapter_cgpa(ArrayList<POJO> cgpaArrayList) {
        this.cgpaArrayList = cgpaArrayList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public adapter_cgpa.Viewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View listitem = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_cgpa, parent, false);
        return new Viewholder(listitem);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull adapter_cgpa.Viewholder holder, int position) {

        POJO cgpa= cgpaArrayList.get(position);
        holder.cname.setText(cgpa.getCname());
        holder.no_of_sems.setText(cgpa.getNo_of_sems());
        holder.cgpa.setText(cgpa.getCgpa());
        holder.percentage.setText(cgpa.getPercentage());
        holder.schemec.setText(cgpa.getSchemec());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return cgpaArrayList.size();
    }

    public class Viewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView cname, no_of_sems, cgpa, percentage,schemec;
        ImageButton btndelete2;


        public Viewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            cname=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            no_of_sems=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.no_of_sem);
            cgpa=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView49);
            percentage=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView55);
            schemec=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.scheme2);
            btndelete2=(ImageButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.btndelete2);

            final String snc = (String) cname.getText();
            final String semrc = (String) no_of_sems.getText();
            final String schc = (String)  schemec.getText();

            btndelete2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dbmanager db= new dbmanager(v.getContext());
                    db.delete2(snc,semrc,schc);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

This is my dbmanager class:

```
public class dbmanager extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    String sgpa_table="create table Sgpa (sname text, semester text, sgpa  text,percent text, schemes text, primary key(sname,semester,schemes))";
    String cgpa_table="create table Cgpa (cname text, no_of_sems int, cgpa text, percentage text, schemec text, primary key(cname,no_of_sems,schemec))";

    public dbmanager(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, "Student", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(sgpa_table);
        db.execSQL(cgpa_table);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }


    public Cursor fetch_data1() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "Select*FROM Sgpa" ;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);

        return cursor;
    }

    public Cursor fetch_data2() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "Select*FROM Cgpa" ;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
//        if (cursor != null) {
//            cursor.moveToFirst();
//        }
        return cursor;

    }

    public Cursor delete2(String snc, String semrc, String schc){
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query= "delete from Cgpa where (cname= ? and no_of_sems = ? and schemec = ?)";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, new String[]{snc,semrc,schc});
        return cursor;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use [`rawQuery()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#rawQuery(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20android.os.CancellationSignal)) to delete rows from a table?
Use [`delete()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#delete(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D)) like this:

```
public boolean delete2(String snc, String semrc, String schc){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    int result = db.delete("Cgpa", "cname= ? and no_of_sems = ? and schemec = ?", new String[] {snc, semrc, schc});
    return result > 0;
}
```

The method returns a `boolean` value: `true` if any row was deleted or `false`.

Comment: The item does not disappear from my recycler view after clicking on delete button. What should I do for that?

Comment: Is it deleted from the table?

Comment: Ohh no.I am sorry. It's still there in the table as well.

Comment: If the method returns `false` then there is no row to be deleted with these values. Replace all: `final String snc = (String) cname.getText();` with `final String snc = cname.getText().toString();`

Comment: First make sure that the item is deleted from the table. If it is not deleted then it does not exist in the table. If it is deleted then delete it from the adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged() for the adapter so it is removed from the recyclerview. But as I said first delete the row from the table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209719/discussion-between-ram-and-forpas).